# How to plot a pandas dataframe with one column as data and the other column as color number?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to make a colored plot based on different labels.
Here is the dataframe df.

```
Date                Close     label
2007-09-18 00:00:00 4546.200195 2
2007-09-19 00:00:00 4732.350098 2
2007-09-20 00:00:00 4747.549805 2
2007-09-21 00:00:00 4837.549805 2
2007-09-24 00:00:00 4932.200195 2
... ... ...
2010-09-24 00:00:00 6018.299805 2
2010-09-27 00:00:00 6035.649902 2
2010-09-28 00:00:00 6029.500000 2
2010-09-29 00:00:00 5991.299805 1
2010-09-30 00:00:00 6029.950195 1
```

I know how to plot it using `plt.scatter()` but I have to provide range index so the x axis gets filled with numbers. I want to plot this data in a way that it looks similar to what I plot by simply doing df['Close'].plot() but with colors which are indicated by df['label'] (For example red for 1, blue for 2) and it has the x axis as date which is the index of the dataframe = df.index.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a color array from the `label` column and plot each point with specific color.

```py
# If you want Date column as index, add the following lines
# df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)


plot = df['Close'].plot()

xs = df.index
ys = df['Close']
colors = df['label'].replace({1: 'red', 2: 'blue'})

for x, y, c in zip(xs, ys, colors):
    plt.scatter(x, y, color=c)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I know how to make it with plt.scatter() like I mentioned above. I am more focused on getting the dates as the x axis

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

my_series = {
'Date': {0: '2021-03-28', 1: '2021-03-29', 2: '2021-03-30'},
'Close': {0: 1000, 1: 1100, 2: 1200},
'label': {0: 1,1: 2,2: 3}
}

colors = ['black', 'blue', 'red', 'green']

df = pd.DataFrame(my_series)
df['color'] = df.apply(lambda row: colors[row.label], axis=1)
plt.scatter(df['Date'], df['Close'], c= df['color'])
```

[image]